# How to reuse/reset jinja filter "joiner"?

Tags: python, templates, filter, jinja2

As per Jinja's [Template Designer Documentation](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/templates/), "A joiner is passed a string and will return that string every time it’s called, **except the first time**."

So, if I were to use this multiple times across my template, the only time it would behave as expected is the first time. Any other times, it would apply the filter before the string.

For example:

```
{% set comma = joiner(", ") %}
{% for version in ssl_versions %}
{{ comma() }}'{{ version }}'
{% endfor %}

{% for backend in auth_backends %}
{{ comma() }}{{ backend }}
{% endfor %}
```

will output:

```
'1', '2', '3'
, backend1, backend2
```

Instead, I want my template to look like this:

```
'1', '2', '3'
backend1, backend2
```

What can I do, other than creating multiple joiners, to achieve this behavior?

Is there a way to reset my joiner variable?

Comment: Why would you rather reset the joiner you have instead of creating a new one (e.g. issuing a `{% set comma = joiner(", ") %}` again)

Comment: Oddly enough, that makes the joiner a "".
Producing 
`'1''2''3'` instead of `'1', '2', '3'`. Have you achieved this behavior? What jinja version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

For the future guys, who will look for answer after 2017:
As for now, you actually can re-create joiner with the same name, by issuing `{% set comma = joiner(", ") %}` again and again. In this case the joiner is reset every time and behave in the way you expecting. 
Checked with Ansible 2.8